# Runtime error on Did End On Exit in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

Does anyone know why im getting runtime error when i click on return button on iphone keyboard. I need to hide keyboard after done editing values to UITextField. So i assigned Did End On Exit to IBAction and the IBAction code below

```
-(IBAction)FinishEditing:(id)sender
{
    [folderName resignFirstResponder];
}
```

When running ma project i facing a runtime error and the variable values shown below

```
argv char ** 0xbffff58c
*argv char * 0xbffff6b8
**argv char '/'
```

Console Value
`(lldb)`

Any idea to overcome this issue??

Comment: variable values shown below
 
argv char ** 0xbffff58c
*argv char * 0xbffff6b8
**argv char '/'

Console Value
(lldb)

Comment: make sure `folderName` is not nil

Comment: ys Maulik that text filed is not nul. it have some value

Comment: nil means check your textField object its IBOutLet should be connect properly... **nil** doesn't mean **empty**. `folderName` is your `textField` object so check it should not be nil.

Comment: Ys i connect those UITextFiled properly..

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html Use this link to get exact point of error. Add exception break point. Hope you will get the point of error in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for helping me. Finally i figure out my issue..

initially my code is like this

```
AddFolder *addButton = [[AddFolder alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddFolder" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:addButton.view];
[addButton release];
```

And now ma code is like this

```
AddFolder *addButton = [[AddFolder alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddFolder" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:addButton.view];
```

We dont need to release memory after adding a subview.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you want to hide `keyboard` on **return button** click of `keyboard`. So there is no need to make any **button action** for this.. you can do that by `UITextField` delegate method. Add `UITextFieldDelegate` in `ViewController.h` file and then simply write below method in `ViewController.m` file :-

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

It would **return** on `return button` click of `keyboard`.

Comment: Vakul i have a doubt on the above code.. Can u please help me to clear.. the above function's return type is bool so how can i connect it to the "Did End On Exit". i think it need a IBAction function.. am i correct??

Comment: "Did End On Exit"  What do you mean by this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the textfield delegate method to do the process .No need to pin the IBActions for this one use

```
– textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
– textFieldDidBeginEditing:
– textFieldShouldEndEditing:
– textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)
and

[This is a nice tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate/)